# Identity Experience Framework - getting the email claim with a multi-tenant Azure AD custom policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I've followed the instructions here to set up the Azure AD multi-tenant custom policy in the Identity Experience Framework:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-commonaad-custom?tabs=applications

However I'm unable to get a claim back containing the email address (corresponding to the "user name" from the external active directory).

The main [single-tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom?tabs=applications) active directory setup works fine, when I use this claim mapping (and the other "social" provider accounts work with `PartnerClaimType="email"`):

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="upn" />
```

However I've tried the following combinations for the multi-tenant, and I don't seem to be getting the data back from the provider:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="upn" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="mail" />
```

Please can someone let me know the correct claim mapping for this, to get the email output from the user flow?

Comment: I believe you are looking for unique_name, but you should do a token request to AAD using POSTman and see the token for yourself to map it properly.

Comment: f my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is "preferred_username".

Add `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="preferred_username" />` into TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml file to see if it works.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works! Do you happen to know if there's a good reference link for finding these partner claim types? (I.e. how to find out that I'd need to use `preferred_username` here) As I'd spent quite some time trying the options above, but I didn't know how to check what possible claim types there are?

Comment: @KevinC. There is no reference link. I find "preferred_username" by using authorization code flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow. Notice you should set "common" as the tenant. After you get id token, you can decode it in https://jwt.io to see  "preferred_username" is one of the claims.

Comment: Thank you, I have searched how to do this for days and tried 5 or 6 different methods, this one works for azure b2c multi tenant apps

Comment: @AllenWu Do you know what `ClaimTypeReferenceId` to specifiy for external single tenant AD? I am not getting the email in the output claim for single tenant as well. I have used `signInNames.emailAddress` for social/local accounts.

Comment: @KevinC what did you use in the Outputclaim for single tenant? it's not working for me.

Comment: @Niladri I don't remember exactly now, but I think after following the instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga the only change I made was to add this `OutputClaim`. As far as I remember this was fine for single-tenant, but didn't work for multi-tenant: `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="upn" />`