# Azure B2C Azure Active Dicrectory retrieve email in token using policies

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, provider

I have an Azure B2C tenant I'm setting up using policies and I'm facing the following problem. One of my social providers is configured as an Azure Active Directory but, when getting the token, the email is not included.

I have other providers like Google or LinkedIn where I've been able to collect the email using these **OutputClaims** inside the **TechnicalProfile** of each **ClaimProvider**.

Google

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email" />
```

LinkedIn

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="elements[0].handle~.emailAddress" />
```

I'm wondering if there is a similar approach to what I need but the Azure Active Directory provide offers an email's **PartnerClaimType**.

I checked the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant-custom?tabs=applications#add-a-claims-provider) for this kind of provider but found nothing. I checked as well the [optional claims set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#v10-and-v20-optional-claims-set) and the email is mentioned but got no clue how to make it work.

Thank's for your time!

Comment: you can see the token coming from AAD. I think it will be upn claim which has the email

Comment: I believe the UPN comes back in a claim called unique_name from AAD. Email in AAD is for users who have an O365 Exchange Online mailbox. UPN is not truly an email. You should manually do an Authorization code flow against AAD to see what the token looks like.

Comment: I found what I needed here: [Identity Experience Framework - getting the email claim with a multi-tenant Azure AD custom policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59272499/identity-experience-framework-getting-the-email-claim-with-a-multi-tenant-azur?rq=1) Now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="unique_name" />
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#claims-in-an-id_token