# Getting otherMails from B2C user in B2C tenant

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

A B2B ('guest') user in a B2C tenant has the otherMails attribute populated, but there doesn't seem to be a way to retrieve it in a flow.

Tried this solution: [email claim in custom policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56194593/why-are-claims-being-flagged-as-not-supported-in-my-custom-policy?newreg=3c3680a583bd4418a8ce208cc2e83444) which works for other IDPs, but not Azure.

Authenticating the B2B user via the details in this article: [B2C Azure multi-tenant provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)

email and upn are not returned in the claim by Azure for a user in another tenant, you only get there objectID and the tenantID of the user.

TIA

Comment: This was the answer... [Getting email claim with multi-tenant policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59272499/identity-experience-framework-getting-the-email-claim-with-a-multi-tenant-azur)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identity Experience Framework - getting the email claim with a multi-tenant Azure AD custom policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59272499/identity-experience-framework-getting-the-email-claim-with-a-multi-tenant-azur)